# Who votes to extend Brexit's deadline?

Tags: european-union, brexit

To give the UK a delay for Brexit, the European Union should unanimously grant the delay. But when we say "unanimously", who votes, who make the decision for each member state?

Answer (score 8):

From [article 50 of the TFEU](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=CELEX%3A12012M050) (emphasis is mine):

> 3. The Treaties shall cease to apply to the State in question from the date of entry into force of the withdrawal agreement or, failing that, two years after the notification referred to in paragraph 2, unless **the European Council, in agreement with the Member State concerned, unanimously decides to extend this period.**

So the European Council has to unanimously agree to extend the article 50 period.

The European Council is made up as follows, [from the EU website](https://www.consilium.europa.eu/en/european-council/):

> The members of the European Council are the heads of state or government of the 28 EU member states, the European Council President and the President of the European Commission.
>
> [...]
>
> If a vote is taken, neither the European Council President nor the Commission President take part.

So, ultimately, the voting will be done by the heads of state or government of the EU27 on the EU side. Specifically, [Wikipedia has a list of who is currently on the European Council](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/European_Council#Members).